# Perl: writing output to different files defined by hashes? (is this even possible?)

Tags: perl, hash

Ok, this piece of code may seem strange, but it's the only way I know how to explain what I want to do:

```
$output{$key1}{$key2} = $filename;
open OUT{$key1}{$key2} , ">$output{$key1}{$key2}" or die "Can't open $output: $filename!\n";

print OUT{$key1}{$key2} "$some_variable{$key1}{$key2}\n";
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. But I need a way to define the output file in a manner similar to this one, because I have 2 key variables in my input file ({$key1}{$key2}) that I have to use to decide which file to write the output to (I want to have as many output files as I have combinations of these two key variables).

I hope my problem is clear, otherwise please let me know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make the filehandle an actual hash of hashes:

```
$output{$key1}->{$key2} = $filename;

open $OUT{$key1}->{$key2} , ">$output{$key1}{$key2}" or die "Can't open $output: $filename!\n"
```

And put braces around the whole thing in the print statement:

```
print {$OUT{$key1}->{$key2}} "$blabla_variable{$key1}{$key2}\n";
```

Comment: The arrows after `}` are optional, though.

Comment: @Dan: Since Perl 5 came out :)